# How to keep code DRY in rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, dry

This is an amazing piece of code when it comes to using ENUM in rails models

```
  STATUS = {  approval: 0, 
              rejected: 1, 
              idle: 2, 
            }

  def status
    STATUS.key(read_attribute(:status))
  end

  def status=(s)
    write_attribute(:status, STATUS[s])
  end
```

It works well when i paste it in any model, and it is exactly the problem. I'm using it many times and so i would like to keep the code DRY.

I tried copying it to `application_helper.rb` but it doesn't work. What is the best way to get it working without repeating in all other models

Code credit: http://www.kensodev.com/tag/enum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code can be abstracted into a module.

```
# lib/enumable.rb
module Enumable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def enum(name, options)
      map = Hash[options.each_with_index.map { |e, i| [e, i] }]

      const_set(name.to_s.pluralize.upcase, map)

      define_method name do
        map.key(read_attribute(name))
      end

      define_method "#{name}=" do |value|
        write_attribute(name, map[value])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

Rails does not autoload from `lib` by default. Add it to the application config.

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

---

Include the new module into your model.

```
# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Enumable
  enum :status, [:approval, :rejected, :idle]
end
```

---

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3-p327 :001 > project = Project.new
 => #<Project id: nil, status: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p327 :002 > project.status = :rejected
 => :rejected 
1.9.3-p327 :003 > project.status
 => :rejected 
1.9.3-p327 :004 > Project::STATUSES
 => {:approval=>0, :rejected=>1, :idle=>2}
```

Comment: FYI- I had trouble using the `define_method` stuff as outlined here. If you don't need the programatically defined stuff here, you can just `def` outside of the `ClassMethods` module.